# Setting a delegate makes app crash

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview

I instantiate a WebViewController to present it modally (UIViewController with a webView in it) and trying to set current class as a delegate for its webView, but it causes app to crash.

```
let webVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
                        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(webVC, animated: true, completion: {
                            webVC.webView.load(data, mimeType: response.mimeType!, textEncodingName: response.textEncodingName!, baseURL: response.url!)
                            webVC.webView.delegate = self
                        })
```

I tried to remove "vc.webView.delegate = self" part, and page loads just fine. Any thoughts what can cause a problem here?

[image]

Comment: Show the implementation of the delegate methods.

Comment: When you crash, what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @shallowThought It is empty right now, so it is not the cause, i think

Comment: @PhillipMills Added to the question

Comment: Is your posted code in your presenting `UIViewController`? Post some more code to see the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is saying that when the `UIWebView` tries to send a message to the delegate, the delegate doesn't exist any more.  That's the normal cause of `objc_msgSend`.  (Or that you've called a method that doesn't exist...but that's unlikely for an optional method.)

Make sure that you remove the delegate before `self` goes out of scope or keep the delegate object around if you need it to handle redirects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

after addSubView, the view of webVC was retained and the webVC was released (as it is a local variable)
you should declare webVC as a global variable, by this way webVC will not be released